# Applying raster manipulation to a lot of rasters

Tags: raster, r

In order to fit some coefficient I used this function :

```
CHLOA = raster(("C:/Users/aurel/Downloads/2013-10-26 (2).tif"), band = 1)
B1 = raster(("C:/Users/aurel/Downloads/2013-10-26 (2).tif"), band = 2)
B2 = raster(("C:/Users/aurel/Downloads/2013-10-26 (2).tif"), band = 3)
B3 = raster(("C:/Users/aurel/Downloads/2013-10-26 (2).tif"), band = 4)
ratio = max(B1, B2)/B3

Modis = raster("C:/Users/aurel/Downloads/2013-10-26.tif")

crop1 = crop(ratio, Modis)
crop2 = crop(Modis, ratio)
resample = resample(crop1, crop2, "bilinear")

stack_v = list(chlor_a = values(resample), layer = values(crop2))

min.RSS = function(data, par){
  sum(
    log(data$chlor_) - 
      (par[1]+par[2]*data$layer +
         par[3]*data$layer^2 +
         par[4]*data$layer^3 + 
         par[5]*data$layer^4)^2,na.rm=TRUE)
}             
optim(par=c(0.30963,-2.40052,1.28932,0.52802,-1.33825), fn=min.RSS, data = stack_v)
```

This basicaly make an optimisation of coefficient by comparing 2 raster from 2 different sources.

What I want to do is to use this optimisation but for comparing a lot of different rasters (397 raster for each source so 397x2).

I tried to stack all the rasters of each sources in order to use the stack_v function on those 2 stack and then doing the optim function on the stack_v element.

To do so I tried to do this :

```
for (i in 2:397) {
  Landsat_B1 <- raster(Landsat_path$V1[i], band = 2)
  Landsat_B2 <- raster(Landsat_path$V1[i], band = 3)
  Landsat_B3 <- raster(Landsat_path$V1[i], band = 4)
  Landsat_ratio = max(B1, B2)/B3
  Modis <- raster(Modis_path$V1[i])
  crop1 = crop(Landsat_ratio, Modis)
  crop2 = crop(Modis, Landsat_ratio)
  resample = resample(crop1, crop2, "bilinear")
}
```

With Landsat_path a list of paths of all the raster from the first source and Modis_path a list of paths of all the raster from the second source.

I'm a little confused on how to do it correctly and if this method is really useful to do what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution by doing a recursive call in my for loop :

```
for (i in 1:397) {
  Landsat_B1 <- raster(Landsat_path$V1[i], band = 2)
  Landsat_B2 <- raster(Landsat_path$V1[i], band = 3)
  Landsat_B3 <- raster(Landsat_path$V1[i], band = 4)
  Landsat_ratio = max(B1, B2)/B3
  Modis <- raster(Modis_path$V1[i])
  crop1 = crop(Landsat_ratio, Modis1)
  crop2 = crop(Modis, Landsat_ratio1)
  resampleL = resample(crop1, crop21, "bilinear")
  resampleM = resample(crop2, crop21, "bilinear")
  resampleL1 = stack(resampleL, resampleL1)
  resampleM1 = stack(resampleM, resampleM1)
}
```

with

`````
CHLOA1 = raster((Landsat_path$V1[1]), band = 1)
B11 = raster((Landsat_path$V1[1]), band = 2)
B21 = raster((Landsat_path$V1[1]), band = 3)
B31 = raster((Landsat_path$V1[1]), band = 4)
Landsat_ratio1 = max(B11, B21)/B31

Modis1 = raster(Modis_path$V1[1])

crop11 = crop(Landsat_ratio1, Modis1)
crop21 = crop(Modis1, Landsat_ratio1)
resampleL1 = resample(crop11, crop21, "bilinear")
resampleM1 = crop21````
`````